# Jquery function load and cache with image

Tags: jquery, load, browser-cache

I try and try fix this but no get , my script in jquery load url and in this url show one image , this image always have the same name in this case "pic.jpg" and this image change each hour , but all time show the same pic and no change showing the new image

My Script it´s this , i try fix using rand url and cache:false , but continue the problem

```
<script>

$.ajaxSetup ({
cache: false
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var auto_refresh = setInterval(

function ()
{   

var randnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*999999999999);
jQuery("#login_data_top_pic_profile").load("index_users.php?load_pic_profile=ok&rand_n="+randnumber);   

},3000);


});
</script>
```

Also i put in php delete cache header and continue no working

It´s possible get some help with my little script for fix this , please , thank´s for the help , regards

P.D : When call from script to index_users.php , always i have this code :

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST[load_pic_profile]=="ok")
{
?>
<img src="profile_user/user1/pic.jpg">
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<img src="profile_user/user1/no_pic.jpg">
<?php
}
?>
```

The image called pic.jpg change always but no his name

Comment: if you go to `index_users.php?load_pic_profile=ok` and load the page several times you get a new image?

Comment: Yes if i go and load the url and change image yes show the new image , i think problem with cache because use the same name always the pic

Comment: Err, I think you're appending the random number to the ajax request and not the image URL. You'll need to append the random number to the image URL instead.

Comment: is `index_users.php` giving the image itself or an element?

Comment: And how ? if append that random number to image the image change the name of image ..... and image always have the same name , if you tell me how fix perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is cached by your browser. Simplest solution is to modify your HTML

```
<img src="pic.jpg?<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

You could also add a `.htaccess` file in the same directory as where your image is

```
<Files "pic.jpg">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do there ? what i see is, you start loading the page... than set an interval to load a image... in your case after 3 seconds. is a script changing the image ? is it really a new image after an hour what you try to load?
sorry for posting here... usual i would post into commencts but i have to less points for that.

Comment: The users for example can change the image from other page , the script load that url each 3 seconds for example and if the pic it´s other simple show , the idea it´s load call this url and the pic always it´s the same name , if th epic change , the script call the same url and must show the new pic , but the name when upload image to profile it´s the same name , only change the pic but with the same name , i test and all works , if reload all page i see the new image but if i try reload with jquery no change , it´s as if the image in cache and only load the first image